# Variable getting scoped inside onAddOriginal event in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-sortablejs

I am using the angular-sortablejs plugin for sorting of the list in my application. Here I have two lists, list A and list B. When I am trying to drop an item from List A to List B, I am triggering `onAddOriginal` event in list B.

where, in this event, I am changing a variable `sortableWidget` value to true. This variable value is getting scoped inside `onAddOriginal` event and I am not able to get the change value of the variable.

Here's my code:

```
selectedWidget: boolean = false  ;
optionsForDroppableArea: SortablejsOptions = {
    group: {
        name: 'widgets',
        put: true,
        pull: true
    },
    onAddOriginal: function (evt) {
        this.selectedWidget = true;
    }
};
```

And when I am consoling the variable, I am getting the value as `false` and not as `true`.

```
deleteRow(){
    console.log(this.selectedWidget);
}
```

Is there any way I could declare a boolean variable as `false`. Then change the value to `true` and able to access this variable all over the code as true. In other words, can I make this variable globally scoped?

Comment: For the `onAddOriginal ` function have you tried using the `=>` notation instead of the keyword function?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. The event `onAddOriginal` itself does not work.